# unabel to launch zenmap in parrot os

Tags: parrot-os

I was trying to install Zenmap in my parrot security os. But after a successful installation  when I am trying to launch Zenmap  of Zenmap, I am getting an ERROR

> File "/usr/bin/zenmap",
> line 114
> except ImportError, e:
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to the same issue by installing the following packages

1. python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
2. python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
3. python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

So I got these packages from wget

`wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

`wget http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject-2/python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

`wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pycairo/python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

and then install these packages by `sudo dpkg -i <package_name.deb>`